# What is the difference between "control flow" and "generic connector" and "object flow" in visual paradigm, (in activity diagram)?

Tags: uml, diagrams, activity-diagram, visual-paradigm

What is the difference between `control flow` and `generic connector` and `object flow` in visual paradigm,  (especially in activity diagram)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know neither visual paradigm nor "generic connector", but I can at least tell the difference between control flow and object flow in UML.

Both are arrows, but serve different purposes.

- A control flow is an arrow that links two actions. For example, it will go from step1 to step2.
- An object flow is an arrow that links an action and an object node. Usually when going from the action to the object, it will mean that the action is somehow modifying the object, and when pointing fron the object to the action it will mean that the action reads the object.

Here a simple example. The object flow is in green just to make the difference but colors don't matter in UML.

[image: simple activity]

Note : As I read through the internet, it seems that a generic connector is just this: a generic connector. Which means it is a connector (a line) linking anything to anything and meaning anything YOU want. But as I said, I don't know visual paradigm so I might be mistaken.

Comment: thank u @Steph so much, It is bothering me for a long time, yes you're right, visual paradigm is a tool to support uml diagrams, so you say the real concept and this is important, thanks.